# NodeJS http server metrics

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have as an assignment to do a nodeJS HTTP server with some form of metrics on it.

**For this assignment, I am not allowed to use any form of external libraries & as the metric of the request I'll store the response time.**

*For route handling ill use a simple switch statement comparing the URL of the request*

```
const http  = require("http");

var metrics = []

http.createServer((req, res) => {
   switch(req.url){
      case "/route"
         var start = Date.now();
         // some code to process the request, maybe some requests to the database, maybe retrieve some files etc
         res.end();
         metrics.push(Date.now() - start);
         break;
   }
}).listen(8080,()=>console.log("Server running!"))
```

The thing is, if I want to do this app with one or a low number of requests this method would be ok,
however, in any other normal scenarios, this would be awful for any further changes to those metrics & much more.

I'm thinking of trying to solve this with some sort of event listeners that I would call at the beginning & the end of my request.
Something that would store information about the request at the beginning & launch an event at the end to stop processing the metrics.

```
server.on('end', (data)=>{
   //end metrics somehow
})
```

Although it seems a little hard to implement, especially as I don't really want to overwrite a nodeJS event to add some data on it ( for instance I may want to add an id of the request, or a timestamp )

Is there a way to properly do this with nodeJS HTTP?

Comment: You have the right idea.  In your calls to `metrics`, you could always put that before the switch statement.  Honestly, all of this is easier with a stack like Express where we can use middleware.  You could recreate that yourself in your own code... it isn't too complicated for the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle it by `finish` event of `res` object. The event will be called when you call `res.end()` (or something like that).

My recommendation, to metrics an API service, you will need more information than response times.

```
const http = require("http");

var metrics = []

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const startPoint = Date.now();
  res.on("finish", () => {
    if (req.url === "/metrics") {
      return; // no metrics for metrics route
    }
    metrics.push({
      path: req.url,
      method: req.method,
      status: res.statusCode,
      dateTime: startPoint,
      times: Date.now() - startPoint,
    });
  });

  switch (req.url) {
    case "/route":
      // some code to process the request, maybe some requests to the database, maybe retrieve some files etc
      setTimeout(() => {
        res.end();
      }, 1000);
      break;
    case "/metrics":
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.write(JSON.stringify(metrics));
      res.end()
      break;
    default:
      res.statusCode = 404;
      res.end();
      break;
  }
}).listen(8080, () => console.log("Server running!"))
```

As you can see, when you call `GET http://localhost:8080/metrics` api, the response will look like this:

```
[
  {
    "path": "/test",
    "method": "GET",
    "status": 404,
    "dateTime": 1613631702906,
    "times": 1
  },
  {
    "path": "/route",
    "method": "GET",
    "status": 200,
    "dateTime": 1613631702906,
    "times": 1004
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

create your own middleware on each routes, if you can't use framework like express or koa

Note: this is the simplest example, but it gives a clue of research

```
class Middleware {
    use(func) {
        this.next_func = (
          (stack) =>
            (next) =>
              stack(
                func.bind(this, next.bind(this)),
              )
        )(this.next_func);
    }
    next_func = (next) => next();
}
```